# Можно ли очистить массив от мусора, но оставить его элементы пустыми?

Tags: c, массивы, динамические-массивы

Допустим, есть массивы:

```
 int * numArr1 = malloc (10*sizeof(int));
 int * numArr2[10];
```

Сейчас там мусор. Я могу очистить мои массивы от мусора, заполнив их нулями(или любыми числами) так:

```
 memset(numArr1, 0, 10*sizeof(int));
 memset(numArr2, 0, 10*sizeof(int));
```

или с помощью calloc:

```
 int * numArr1 = calloc (10*sizeof(int));
 int * numArr2 = calloc (10*sizeof(int));
```

Или в цикле, но все эти способы предполагают заполнение массивов какими-то значениями сразу. Есть ли в СИ способ просто выделить блок памяти под массив, но оставить его пустым? (ну или хотя бы заполнить какой-то специальной константой которая не влияла бы на вычисления).

Comment: что значит "оставить его пустым"?

Comment: @timur чтоб там не было "ничего" ни нулей ни других кодов.

Comment: там не может быть ничего. Что-то должно быть

Comment: @Konstantin_SH - так физически невозможно. int - это просто 32 бита (обычно). Каждый бит или 1 или 0. Находится в суперпозиции они пока не могут.

Comment: Ха-ха, во многих системах `malloc()`, а чаще `calloc()` **именно так и делают!** Просто в первом случае вы получаете адрес, который просто зарезервирован под ваш массив + что библиотека Си довесила, а во втором — скорее всего вообще выдаётся вам т.н. "нулевая страница", то есть ничего не существует, пока вы записывать не начнёте. Если не хотите библиотеки Си, то `mmap()` вам в помощь.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH  - Вы осознаёте, что оператор "int * numArr2[10];" создаёт **не** массив целых, а массив **указателей** на целое? К постановке вопроса это не относится. просто, на всякий случай..

Comment: @Sergey Да, я в курсе))

Answer (score 2):

Система лишь находит место в памяти, которое можно отдать под использование программе. Что там лежит — неважно. Задача функции выделения памяти — выделить память. У нее нет задачи заполнять чем—то этот кусок памяти. Все эти циклы для заполнения нулем или calloc это всё не на уровне системы, а уже на уровне программы.
Как было сказано выше, что значит оставить его пустым?

Answer (score 1):

У вас странное задание - "выделить блок памяти под массив, но оставить его пустым"

Что вы понимаете под "пустой"? Если вы выделили блок памяти - он уже не пустой, в нем *всегда* будут какие-то значения. Если вы хотите *инициализировать* массив нулевыми значениями - укажите это сразу:

```
int a[1000] = {};
```

или

```
int * a = new int[1000]{};
```

Comment: В языке C нет выражения `new`